# Autoexport bash internal variables

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

I need to access to some bash internal variables (BASH_LINENO, BASH_SOURCE) from a command invoked by a shell script. The only possible interface between my command and the script are environment variables. Is there any way to configure bash in order to make global some internal variables:

Example:

```
myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash

# ... some scripting stuff ...

mycommand  # LINENO=4, BASH_SOURCE=([0]="myscript.sh")

# ... some other scripting stuff ...
```

So the thing I need is that when bash invoke mycommand; $LINENO and $BASH_SOURCE (internal variables) become global, in order for my command to access to them.

I'm not looking for commands like:

```
declare -x LINENO
```

Because `LINENO` change over time, if I do this `declare -x LINENO` the new global variable `LINENO` takes the value of the `LINENO` (internal) at this point in time. I need this thing to be dynamic so the global `LINENO` reflects the `LINENO` value in every change.

In programming words: I want to change the scope of these variables from internal to global or make something like a pointer.

Comment: @John1024, I've just modified the question to add information. It's my first time here, so please ask again if you need more information.

Comment: Very good.  Can your `mycommand` be made to accept command line arguments as in `mycommand "$LINENO" "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`?

Comment: @John1024, sadly no. The only interface between `mycommand` and the shell must be environment variables.

Comment: How about invoking `mycommand` with a line like `line=$LINENO src="$BASH_SOURCE[0]}" mycommand` and then having `mycommand` inspect the `line` and `src` variable?

Comment: @John1024: I really want to avoid do that, because it forces the users of mycommand to remember all the variables needed by mycommand. But if it can be done in the form of a function or alias for mycommand so becomes transparent to the user of mycommand it would be perfect.